# How to associate the comment form with the correct post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have user/micropost/comment models where users can comment on others' microposts. Under every post a textfield is shown so that users can enter comments however I am struggling to get find the Micropost Id. I assume the issue is in my form_for comments or the controllers but I am not really sure. Would love some help, thanks.

Error: Couldn't find micropost without an ID

Models:

```
User Model: has many microposts, has many comments
Micropost Model: belongs to user, has many comments
Comment Model: belongs to micropost, belongs to user
```

User Controller:

```
def show #(the profile page where all the posts and comments are)
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build if signed_in?
  @comments = @micropost.comments
  @comment = current_user.comments.build(:micropost => @micropost) if signed_in?
end
```

Comment Controller:

```
def create
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  @comment = current_user.comments.build(:micropost => @micropost) #can someone explain what happens in the parentheses? 
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comment.save
  redirect_to :back
end
```

View/comments/_comment_form:

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <div id="comment_field">
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Say Something..." %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
resources :users
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add a hidden field for the micropost_id

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :micropost_id, value: @micropost.id %>
  <div id="comment_field">
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Say Something..." %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE: passing `micropost_id` without any changes to the controller

Based on your comments controller, you're finding `micropost` based on `params[:id]` which is missing when you submit the form.  The code below fixes that.  However, I suggest you look at nested resources which will make the controller code prettier and more slick

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :id, @micropost.id %>
  <div id="comment_field">
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Say Something..." %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

or update the `action` of the form

```
<%= form_for @comment, url: comments_path(id: @micropost.id) do |f| %>
  <div id="comment_field">
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Say Something..." %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE: with edits to the comment controller

```
# view
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :micropost_id, @micropost.id %>
  <div id="comment_field">
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Say Something..." %>
  </div>
<% end %>

# comments_controller.rb

def create
  @micropost = Micropost.find params[:micropost_id]
  @comment = current_user.comments.build
  @comment.micropost = @micropost
  @comment.save
end
```

Comment: I still get the same error no micropost id found pointing to the comment controller create method

Comment: I've adjusted my answer based on your current controller code :)

Comment: The problem I'm having is that in the comment controller Micropost find params id comes back as nil. I don't know how to target the right post. When I declare the value of the micropost in the form_for to say 4 it inserts the comment in the db But I had to change the @comment in the controller to = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])

Comment: yes I know that. that's why I added the `hidden field` on the first solution. and on the second solution, I've added the id on the route which is the same.

Comment: I'm pretty confused. I tried both of the form fors you posted after the update and I get the error Couldn't find Micropost without an ID because in the SQL the micropost_id parameter is still blank

Comment: i've updated my answer again including changes to your controller

Comment: Do my resources have to be nested? When I nest them i get no route matches for POST

Comment: Sorry for struggling to understand

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24023/discussion-between-jvnill-and-ayounesi)

Answer (score 1):

Yous should setup your comment resources in this way:

```
resources :users
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy] do
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

The above resources are called nested resources. And as in your case the comment always relate to a micropost, you should ***nest*** comment resources into **microposts**
and in the Comment Controller:

```
def create
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  @comment = current_user.comments.build(:micropost => @micropost) #can someone explain what happens in the parentheses?
  @comment.save
  redirect_to :back
end
```

The build method above creates a new object/instance of Comment model and as you have used `current_user.comments` that means, the object will have `user_id = current_user.id` automatically you don't need to specify it again. And 'build(:micropost => @micropost)' will add the `micropost's id` to `@comment` object.